# Is there a way to give live input to a script run by the shell?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, sh

So I made a keyboard shortcut to run a shell script. It runs mplayer which usually is run in the terminal and controlled with keyboard input. i.e arrow keys for skipping back and fourth in the song.

But since I ran it through a shell script, I can't just simply press arrow keys to control it anymore.

Is there a way to create a second shell script or maybe write some program to take input through keyboard shortcuts?

So for example I would launch the script through the keyboard shortcut, then through (either the same script, some code, or a second script?) press Ctrl+Alt+Right to skip the song forward and Ctrl+Alt+Right to skip backwards in the song.

Comment: Can't you focus the video window and use left/right as normal?

Comment: Does this help?  https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/pause-mplayer-in-background-from-command-line-897703/ ... 15 seconds of googling ;) ... then just define key-bindings in your DE/WM.

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes it's hard to know what to google.